# Google permission issue

Tags: android-manifest

Google Play Store permission issue.

These are my Android (permission) manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

This is the message I get:

> Based on our review, we found your app’s expressed user experience did
>   not match your declared core functionality {Account verification via
>   phone call}. Please remove these permissions from your app.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to Fill-up Google Docs for permission.
Make sure your permission is given in manifest and give the pop up at user level.
Contact google developers for Details.

[Use of SMS or Call Log permission groups](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)

Answer (score 0):

Your playstore account is not verified via phone (email you use to make account on playstore does not have mobile number verified.)

And you did not mention rest of email specially after they said

> Please remove these permissions from your app.

After this they must mentioned some permission names to remove. you can use google support chat using play console and talk to them directly.